# Put activity window inside jetpack compose app

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a camera written in java, AppCompact Activity and I have the following jetpack compose code

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(color = Background)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(20.dp)
    ) {
        HeaderText(title = "Sample header")
        ParagraphText(title = stringResource(id = R.string.lorem_ipsum))
        CameraSelectDropDown(selectedCamera = selectedCamera)
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 20.dp, bottom = 20.dp).fillMaxWidth().height(300.dp))
        //i wish to put my camera activity here
    }
```

when I put my camera activity, it just navigates to it because I use this line

```
context.startActivity(Intent(context, ExampleActivity::class.java))
```

How can I place the activity in that portion of my compose app?

Comment: Replace `ExampleActivity` with a composable that you can place in your desired location.

Comment: so then I start the activity in another composable which is going to be used on the code above and the activity will be placed inside the column of the above composable?

Comment: @EMT you want direct redirection or after click on any view ?

Comment: i want to load my composable as well as activity on the same page

Comment: "so then I start the activity in another composable" -- my recommendation is that you have one activity, not two.

Comment: it did not work,